# Show html in angular if $location matches

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, location

I am trying to get some html to show only on one of the paths in my app in angular, but cant seem to get the `ng-if` to function correctly.

Here is what I have

In Controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() { 
    $scope.appLocation = $location.$$path;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="{{appLocation}} == '/channels'">
    <!-- html to show -->
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need the curly braces `{{ }}`. So, `<div ng-if="appLocation === '/channels'">`

Comment: Should have tried that. But that did the trick. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @New Dev comment resolve your problem for sure but with just double equal == not a triple one ===, simply because angular expressions don't support === operator(!=== too). Maybe it was fixed but I had problems with the triple equal!

So it will be <div ng-if="appLocation == '/channels'">

Source : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/901